# AES Encryption Not Working Properly in UWP

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, openssl, aes

We have an C++ application where it encrypts password using AES algorithm through openssl API's (**EVP_EncryptInit_ex, EVP_EncryptUpdate, EVP_EncryptFinal_ex**).

Now I try to develop UWP application through which I want to do same authentication as the above legacy app does.

But when I'm using API's from **"Windows.Security.Cryptography"** my authentication fails as the encrypted data output is different from the legacy app, so decryption fails and there by authentication.

Legacy app uses one Key and initialization vector and same are used in my UWP app also. Legacy app uses cipher mode CBC, I had used **"AesCbcPKCS7"** in my UWP but the encrypted output is different.

I also tried just **"AesCbc"** and padded data as per PKCS7 padding manually still the encrypted output is different and my authentication is failing.

Kindly help with the above issue.

Some of Legacy App Code API Flow Sample:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, output, &nOutputSize, input, strlen((const char *)input)+1);
EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx, output + nOutputSize, &nTmplen);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
```

UWP Code sample below:

```
IBuffer iBuf = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(strPwd, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);            
IBuffer iPubKey = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(PUB_KEY);

SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);
CryptographicKey cryptKey = objAlg.CreateSymmetricKey(iPubKey);
IBuffer iv = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(INIT_VECTOR);

IBuffer encryptPwd = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cryptKey, iBuf, iv);
string strEncPwd = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encryptPwd);
```

Comment: Pls also provide C++ code, with compilation steps if that matters.

Comment: Updated my question with the source. Those are the series of API calls made in legacy app to encrypt the password.

Comment: Why do you use names like PUB_KEY & iPubKey in relation to a symmetric keys ? I would expect a variable with that name to contain a public key, but then again I would not expect a public key as input to CreateSymmetricKey(..) .. what is the content of PUB_KEY ?

Comment: I already explained in my question, however i can't share the key as it is confidential. The legacy app already uses a key and IV to encrypt. So I'm also using same key and IV. For CreateSymmetricKey we need to pass the key material, which in general will be a random key but here the key material is generated using the existing legacy key.

Comment: Even same key is used as input in the legacy sample code pasted above, there in the "EVP_EncryptInit_ex" api call "key" variable holds the key, same is used in uwp code also.

Comment: Kindly any one help me with the issue...

Comment: It would be much easier if you could provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with expected correct output, so that other people can easily run the example locally, rather than having to copy paste the code snippet and figure out what else is needed to make it actually run.  Generate a new key to use and share in the example, so you don't have to share real secrets.

Comment: Issue is not with these Cryptography API's, If i use some random generated key i was able to encrypt and decrypt and get my actual data. But issue is with some existing system where my legacy app encrypts password using a key in a certain steps, so same way it is decrypted at other end and is getting authenticated. So I have to test with the same key, and my UWP app should also be able to authenticate with the same  system but which is not happening even though I follow same set of steps and algorithms used.

Comment: Only difference I see is legacy app directly uses EVP.h API's from openssl directly, but I'm using Win 10 cryptography namespace API's but underlying as it is same AES and same CBC cipher mode is used still why the data is being differently encrypted.

Comment: Without a sample of the encrypted and unencrypted data, and they key used, I can't guess what's wrong. Maybe the legacy app is encrypting the data wrong, so using crypto APIs in a different language will be difficult because you have to do it the same wrong way if you can't fix the legacy app. Or maybe you think you're using the same crypto algorithm, but actually you're using different algorithms. Have you tried using [AesCryptoProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Also, you keep writing about decrypting a password in your .NET app, but in your sample you wrote `CryptographicEngine.Encrypt`. Did you try `Decrypt`?

Comment: AesCryptoServiceProvider is available from .NET Std 2.0 but for some reasons my UWP app min version is 10.0.15063, so this was not available.
And I tried decrypt and i was able to get my original data as encryption and decsryption is done in same way. but as said before I'm authenticating with an existing system where it is failing because legacy app uses direct openssl API's. I'm not sure what was the difference it does even if I use same AES and CBC mode similar to my legacy app.

Comment: Having said above all, however I tried compiling Microsoft OpenSSL and included that uwp compatible libeay32.lib and it started authenticating as it generates same encrypted content as my legacy app does. Now still I don't know what's the difference between UWP encrypt API and openssl API and why it generates different, even after I tried same way of implementation.

Comment: I used same key and Init vector, same AES CBC mode but in legacy app padding is not done explicitly in the code might be openssl api's internally does that. Still I tried all kind of paddings keeping "AesCbc" instead of "AesCbcPkcs7" but still the encrypted output remains different except after which I tried openssl as said above comment. Kindly tell me what's the reason or difference.