# How to use OpenSSL dll for UWP Apps

Tags: uwp, openssl, nuget

I wanted to use the OpenSSL API's instead of API's from `Windows.Security.Cryptogrpahy`, due some issue as described in below link:

[AES Encryption Not Working Properly in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54005487/aes-encryption-not-working-properly-in-uwp)

I referred to many nuget packages but none were getting installed for UWP app. For ex: `OpenSSL.Static.Uwp` which fails saying

> it doesn't support any target frameworks

I also referred [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/openssl) MSFT OpesSSL github source.

I compiled as per the instructions in "**INSTALL.WINUNIVERSAL**" but how to use the dll `libeay32.dll` in UWP C# app?

I tried adding the dll as Content, but I don't have info of Publisher and Version in the above compiled process to provide in the **PackageDependency** in manifest. Also I couldn't make use of `LoadPackagedLibrary` in my C# UWP app.

How to get OpenSSL dll `libeay32.dll` integrated with C# UWP App. Or tell any nuget library that gets installed successfully.

Comment: Any one with any solution or faced same scenario, please help

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL is a C library, it would not work from C# directly since C# is managed language but C is native one. Since UWP doesn't allow DllExport (as I know),  to achieve that you would need to write [runtime component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/) library using C++/CX or C++/WinRT language with a simple top API you gonna call from your app using direct OpenSSL calls under the hood. For easy start I suggest to use [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) idiom.

Now, you know how to link your libraries to project, let's talk about options available. Of coulse you could build it manually from available MS fork (as you did already), the higher version you able to get this way is 1.0.2, 1.1.1 was abandoned some time ago. Another way is to use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenSSL.Static.Uwp) nuget package, it will build appropriate OpenSSL 1.0.2, take a look at linked github page for further info, it's based on same MS repo.

As you see there no "ready to go" option to get latest OpenSSL 1.1.1, but you are able to build UWP compatible OpenSSL from official master branch! It become possible because of [that](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/8917) pull request and it been merged to master [recently](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/5ded1ca6dade13e093086573f4cebe400bff9f4d), well, as long as it's [OpenSSL 3.0.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/OpenSSL300Design.html) you still have full backward compatibility with 1.1.1, though there no any stable release so far, so decision to use or not it's all up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this had been posted a long while ago, I have already achieved this using c++ WinRT component. I built the ssl libs for universal platform after lot of struggle based on the instructions, and used these libs in my winrt component.

Comment: Hey @SiD good to hear you solved your problem! It's a good practice here to post answer even in case you solved it by yourself :) Anyway I'm sure it will help other people who face similar issue.